# How to run commands in a file inside database console?

Tags: database, informix

Can someone please tell whether is it possible to run a shell script inside of a database.

*Scenario:*

Using database Informix. I have a script in a file having multiple insert statements. I am opening the database connection. Creating some temporary tables and performing some joins. In order to load data into a temporary table I need the insert statements in that "file".

*Question:*

Is there a way or workaround so that I can run commands in that file inside database console? As I am creating several temp tables I cannot afford to close the database connection.

Comment: cut & paste from the file?

Comment: @MarcB.....Soory Mark but I cannot do this. I am running a shell script that opens the database connection. I hope you are getting what is the issue.

Comment: gotcha. does informix have a command line interface along the lines of what mysql has? `mysql < commands.sql` with whatever informix's equivalent would be the way to go.

Comment: @MarcB....I am just using putty terminal to run the shell script. Inside this shell script I am making connection to informix server using dbaccess $DBNAME <<.
Now here I am creating temp tables, so I cannot afford to close the connection and execute another script.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To pass a script to a database connection on the command line, you do the following:

```
dbaccess [databasename] file.sql
```

or

```
dbaccess filename.sql
```

(if the file contains a `DATABASE` statement at the top.)

To insert data whilst processing that file, make sure the file contains something like:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE foo (bar INT, baz CHAR(10));
LOAD FROM "foodata.unl" DELIMITER "|"
INSERT INTO foo;

SELECT ...
```

**UPDATE TO ORIGINAL ANSWER**

To embed SQL in a shell script, you can use a 'here document' approach, which I think is what you're alluding to:

```
#!/bin/ksh

echo "Starting"

dbaccess << EOSQL

    DATABASE foo;

    CREATE TEMP TABLE foobar (foo INT, bar CHAR(10));
    LOAD FROM "foobar.unl" DELIMITER "|"
    INSERT INTO foobar;

    SELECT ...

    UPDATE ...

EOSQL

echo "Finished"
```

Now you can tweak the behaviour of that SQL by using script or environment variables if need be...

```
SELECT * FROM foobar WHERE bar > $VALUE;
```

where `$VALUE` will be interpolated by the shell for you at run time, and fed to the Informix database as if it were hard-coded.

You can even inject whole SQL by embedding a sub-shell process...

```
dbaccess << EOSQL

    DATABASE foo;

    CREATE TEMP TABLE ...

    `cat $PATH_TO/some_more_sql_in_an_external_file.sql`

    UPDATE ...

EOSQL
```

And even that will be treated by the dbaccess process as if it were all part of the here document (but this is a rare and frankly pretty bizarre thing to do).

*However*, if what you are asking is can you somehow pause or interrupt the query in order to affect it somehow, examine the contents of the temp table or alter it in some way, the answer is no, you can't.

One more trick worth remembering. Setting the environment variable `DBACCNOIGN` to a non-zero value will force any error in the here doc SQL processing to abort the entire chain of processing. The default behaviour of dbaccess is to report the error and move onto the next statement.

I hope that helps.

Comment: @RET....i have already made the database connection using dbaccess $DBNAME <<. inside my shell script. Now, how can I run a sql script inside my shell script Content of file.ksh is sth like dbaccess $DBNAME <<. 
create temp table
how can I run sql command here ??
.
Any idea... please suggest

Comment: See updated answer. If what I've written still doesn't help, please consider amending your original question with more detail. It's still not crystal clear what you're having problems doing.